# importar imagem da galeria - android

Tags: android-studio, sqlite, sqlite3

Eai pessoal, preciso de ajuda com a minha aplicação, eu tenho q selecionar uma imagem da galeria, fazer ela aparecer em uma imageView e salvar ela no banco(SQLite), para q a pessoa possa sair do aplicativo e manter a foto para quando retornar, isso já ajuda muito e se for possivel fazer com que a aplicação tire uma foto com uma qualidade descente e também mostre na imageview e salve no banco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segue exemplo do que precisa:
1) Mostra na tela opção de escolha: seleciona foto da galeria ou tira foto;
2) Mostra na imageview;
3) Faz upload numa web api, eu uso para o asp.net mvc mas pode ser usado para outras linguagens também;

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btnChooseImage:
            final CharSequence[] items = { "Take Photo", "Choose from Library",
                    "Cancel" };
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(UploadDocumentsActivity.this);
            builder.setTitle("Add Photo!");
            builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                    boolean result= UtilityPermission.checkPermission(UploadDocumentsActivity.this);
                    if (items[item].equals("Take Photo")) {
                        userChoosenTask="Take Photo";
                        if(result)
                            cameraIntent();
                    } else if (items[item].equals("Choose from Library")) {
                        userChoosenTask="Choose from Library";
                        if(result)
                            galleryIntent();
                    } else if (items[item].equals("Cancel")) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }
            });
            builder.show();
            break;
        case R.id.btnUploadImage:
            uploadImage();
            break;

    }
}

private void galleryIntent()
{
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);//
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select File"),SELECT_FILE);
}

private void cameraIntent()
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_FILE) {
            if (data != null) {
                try { bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), data.getData());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        else if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA) {
            bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bytes);
            File destination = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                    System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");
            FileOutputStream fo;
            try {
                destination.createNewFile();
                fo = new FileOutputStream(destination);
                fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
                fo.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        imgForUpload.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
}

private void uploadImage(){
    class UploadImage extends AsyncTask<Bitmap,Void,String> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            hideProgressDialog();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            if (response.length() == 0)
            {
                resultRequest = false;
                errorMessage  = "Image has uploaded successfull";
                ShowAlert();
                if (lastActivity.equals("Profile")) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(UploadDocumentsActivity.this, MenuPageActivity.class);
                    obj.setLastActivity("UploadDocuments");
                    startActivity(i);
                }
                else
                {
                    Intent i = new Intent(UploadDocumentsActivity.this, VehicleActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                resultRequest = false;
                errorMessage  = "Server is not responding or internet is not working, try later";
                ShowAlert();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Bitmap... params) {
            obj  = (AppController) getApplicationContext();
            String url = "http://server/xx";
            String final_upload_filename = "demo_image.png";
            HttpURLConnection conn = null;
            try {
                String lineEnd = "\r\n";
                String twoHyphens = "--";
                String boundary = "---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
                URL urlDestiny = new URL(url);
                conn = (HttpURLConnection) urlDestiny.openConnection();
                conn.setDoInput(true);
                conn.setDoOutput(true);
                conn.setUseCaches(false);
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + obj.getToken());
                conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
                DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd + twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + param + "\"; filename=\"" + 
                                final_upload_filename + "\"" + lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes("Content-Type: application/octet-stream" + lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, dos);
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);
                dos.flush();
                dos.close();
                InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                int bytesRead;
                byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
                while ((bytesRead = is.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                    baos.write(bytes, 0, bytesRead);
                }
                byte[] bytesReceived = baos.toByteArray();
                baos.close();
                is.close();
                response = new String(bytesReceived);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (conn != null) {
                    conn.disconnect();
                }
            }
            return response;
        }
    }
    UploadImage ui = new UploadImage();
    ui.execute(bitmap);
}
```

Comment: ja tinha visto um código parecido, se eu não me engano esta faltando um arquivo java com as permissões, seria bom um xml do layout, e eu não entendi a parte 3 upload numa web api, eu só queria salvar nem q fosse o caminho no banco , vc não conhece nenhuma forma simples de se fazer isso ?

Comment: Não conheço opção mais simples, esta é a que uso e funciona muito bem. Sim, as permissões é requisito obrigatório em versões mais novas do android, eu enxuguei o código para ficar somente o que pediu. A opção 3 (web api) é o servidor ao qual será encaminhado a imagem para que seja gravado no servidor no servidor, ou seja, numa pasta onde está hospedado o servidor e também é gravado o endereço deste caminho (link) no banco de dados para que futuramente, quando o usuário entrar neste registro tanto pelo mobile quanto por uma aplicação web ele possa ver a imagem que foi gravada.

Comment: minha necessidade é cadastrar apenas no banco local (SQLite) é desnecessário essa opção na minha aplicação, mas de qualquer forma obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: Blz...então esta ultima parte é mais simples. Como ainda não fiz gravação local não tenho como lhe ajudar...se o trecho acima lhe ajudar, dê um Up ai pra nós...